# Find nested elements with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to search an Input inside of a Div, but I don't know the exactly name of the Div, the div name can be:
EditContactModalDiv01,
EditContactModalDiv02,
EditContactModalDiv03 etc.

The exactly name of the input is "Address".
Between both div and input there are other elements, divs, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

//update

Is there a common class for those div if so u can do a

```js
$('.commonClass').each(function () { 
  var searchValue = $(this).find('input[name="Address"]').val();
});
```

//

On what event are you trying to find the input ? Coz otherwise there is no point in this question.

You shall use $("input[name="Address"]") to find a input field in general. if you have a event on which this should trigger you can use a reference attached to the input selector.

Answer (score 0):

if name of the textbox is exactly "Address" then you can use following code

```
$("input[name='Address']")
```

if textbox name is not same all the time but there is only one input within the div then you can use following code

```
$( "div[id^='EditContactModalDiv']" ).find("input")
```

Comment: The input name is exactly Address, but isn't unique.

Comment: in that case you can use $( "div[id^='EditContactModalDiv']" ).find("input[name='Address']")

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#EditContactModalDiv01,#EditContactModalDiv01,#EditContactModalDiv01').find('input[name=Address]')
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Rino_Raj/4qwzpx52/7/)